# Using the right api_version of the azure SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to verify the existence of some resources in my tenant.
I use the `ResourceManagementClient` to do so, either the `check_existence_by_id` method or `get_by_id` as described in [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/2808) issue.

My script uses a constant api_version for now, "2022-09-01", which apparently isn't supported for every resource type, because I sometimes get a `NoRegisteredProviderFound` like this:

```
HttpResponseError: (NoRegisteredProviderFound) No registered resource provider found for location 'westeurope' and API version '2022-03-01' for type 'firewallPolicies'. The supported api-versions are '2019-06-01, 2019-07-01, 2019-08-01, 2019-09-01, 2019-11-01, 2019-12-01, 2020-01-01, 2020-03-01, 2020-04-01, 2020-05-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-07-01, 2020-08-01, 2020-11-01, 2021-01-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-03-01, 2021-04-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-06-01, 2021-08-01, 2021-12-01, 2022-01-01, 2022-05-01, 2022-07-01, 2022-09-01'. The supported locations are 'qatarcentral, uaenorth, australiacentral2, uaecentral, germanynorth, centralindia, koreasouth, switzerlandnorth, switzerlandwest, japanwest, francesouth, southafricawest, westindia, canadaeast, southindia, germanywestcentral, norwayeast, norwaywest, southafricanorth, eastasia, southeastasia, koreacentral, brazilsouth, brazilsoutheast, westus3, jioindiawest, swedencentral, japaneast, ukwest, westus, eastus, northeurope, westeurope, westcentralus, southcentralus, australiaeast, australiacentral, australiasoutheast, uksouth, eastus2, westus2, northcentralus, canadacentral, francecentral, centralus'.
Code: NoRegisteredProviderFound
```

From what I've seen, the interfaces I use remain similar to the client for each version, but the Azure API service for some reason doesn't support them all.

How can I determine a right version to use for each resource type during runtime? the list of resources I want to query is huge and has many types of resources.

**Edit:** The answer that @SiddheshDesai provided works perfectly but if you face a similar issue when using the `ResourceMangamentClient` I also recommend trying the `ResourceGraphClient` from `azure.mgmt.resoucegraph`. It provides an interface that lets you query the same information very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the right version for each resource types in Azure with the Python code below:-

```py
from  azure.identity  import  AzureCliCredential

from  azure.mgmt.resource  import  ResourceManagementClient

  

# Initialize the Azure credentials

credential = AzureCliCredential()

subscription_id = 'subscription-id'

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

  

provider_namespace = 'Microsoft.Network'  # replace with your desired provider namespace

provider = resource_client.providers.get(provider_namespace)

  

for  resource_type  in  provider.resource_types:

print(f"Resource Type: {resource_type.resource_type}")

print(f"Latest API Version: {resource_type.api_versions[0]}")

print('\n')
```

Output:-

[image]

The above code listed the Resource types and their API versions for the resource provider Microsoft.Network.
Now, To check if the particular resource exists by its Id with the resource type, you can use the python script below:-

I have deployed one V-NET in my account:-

[image]

Python code:-

```py
rom  azure.identity  import  AzureCliCredential

from  azure.mgmt.resource  import  ResourceManagementClient

  

# Initialize the Azure credentials

credential = AzureCliCredential()

subscription_id = 'subscription-id'

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

  

# Dictionary to store the API version for each resource type

api_versions = {}

  

# List of resource types to check existence for

resource_types = ['Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts']

  

for  resource_type  in  resource_types:

# Split the resource type into its provider namespace and resource type

provider_namespace, type_name = resource_type.split('/', 1)

# Check if the API version for this resource type has already been determined

if  type_name  in  api_versions:

api_version = api_versions[type_name]

else:

# Get the list of API versions for this resource type

provider = resource_client.providers.get(provider_namespace)

api_versions[type_name] = provider.resource_types[0].api_versions[0]

api_version = api_versions[type_name]

# Use the determined API version to check if the resource exists

resource_id = '/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/{2}/{3}'.format(subscription_id, 'resource-group-name', provider_namespace, type_name)

try:

resource = resource_client.resources.get_by_id(resource_id, api_version)

print(f"{resource_type} exists.")

except:

print(f"{resource_type} does not exist.")
```

Output:-

[image]